# select query that subracts two tables and if more data in child then should not consider it

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

```
create table oms (run_date date,ban varchar2(10),DVR_IND char(1));

create table enab (run_date date,ban varchar2(10),DVR_IND char(1));
```

Master table

```
    insert into oms values(trunc(sysdate),'1111111111','Y');  
    insert into oms values(trunc(sysdate),'1111111111','Y'); 
    insert into oms values(trunc(sysdate),'1111111111','Y'); 
    insert into oms values(trunc(sysdate),'2222222222','Y'); 
    insert into oms values(trunc(sysdate),'3333333333','Y'); 
    insert into oms values(trunc(sysdate),'3333333333','N'); 
    insert into oms values(trunc(sysdate),'4444444444','Y'); 
    insert into oms values(trunc(sysdate),'4444444444','Y'); 
    insert into oms values(trunc(sysdate),'4444444444','Y'); 
    insert into oms values(trunc(sysdate),'4444444444','Y'); 
    insert into oms values(trunc(sysdate),'4444444444','N'); 
    insert into oms values(trunc(sysdate),'4444444444','N');
```

and child table :

```
    insert into enab values(trunc(sysdate),'1111111111','Y');  
    insert into enab values(trunc(sysdate),'2222222222','Y'); 
    insert into enab values(trunc(sysdate),'3333333333','Y'); 
    insert into enab values(trunc(sysdate),'3333333333','Y'); 
    insert into enab values(trunc(sysdate),'3333333333','N'); 
    insert into enab values(trunc(sysdate),'4444444444','Y'); 
    insert into enab values(trunc(sysdate),'4444444444','N'); 
    insert into enab values(trunc(sysdate),'5555555555','N');
```

Query should return these records :

```
    insert into oms values(trunc(sysdate),'1111111111','Y'); 
    insert into oms values(trunc(sysdate),'1111111111','Y'); 
    insert into oms values(trunc(sysdate),'4444444444','Y'); 
    insert into oms values(trunc(sysdate),'4444444444','Y'); 
    insert into oms values(trunc(sysdate),'4444444444','Y');
```

Result of all records should have DVR_IND= 'Y'

1. For ban 1111111111 total count in OMS is 3 and in enab is 1 result is(3-1) = 2
2. For ban 2222222222 total count in OMS is 1 and in enab is 1 result is(1-1) = 0
3. For ban 3333333333 total count in OMS is 1 and in enab is 2 result is (1-2) = 0 (because we need to consider oms table and dvr_ind='Y')
4. For ban 4444444444 total count in OMS is 4 and in enab is 1 result is (4-1) = 3

So total  count is = 2+0+0+3 = 5 (i want to get those five records)

Comment: `varchar2()` screams Oracle so I fixed the database tags.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: i want the query to get that result

Comment: I don't understand the "*answer should be: ...*" part. Do you want the query to return formatted `insert` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate rows with `row_number()` and left join tables using values and this counter:

```
select run_date, ban, dvr_ind
    from (
      select o.*, o.rowid, 
          row_number() over (partition by run_date, ban, dvr_ind order by null) rn 
        from oms o) o
    left join (
      select e.*, e.rowid,
          row_number() over (partition by e.run_date, e.ban, e.dvr_ind order by null) rn 
        from enab e) e using (run_date, ban, dvr_ind, rn)
    where e.rowid is null;
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5cdef/1)</sup>

In your examples for ban='4444444444' there are 6 rows in `oms` and 2 matching in `enab` (not 4 and 1 like you have written in description), 
so output is little different.

---

**Edit:** I didn't notice, that you are only interested in rows with dvr_ind = 'Y'. So add `where dvr_ind = 'Y'` in both subqueries (or in last line):

```
select run_date, ban, dvr_ind
    from (
      select o.*, o.rowid,
          row_number() over (partition by run_date, ban, dvr_ind order by null) rn
        from oms o where dvr_ind = 'Y') o
    left join (
      select e.*, e.rowid,
          row_number() over (partition by e.run_date, e.ban, e.dvr_ind order by null) rn
        from enab e where dvr_ind = 'Y') e using (run_date, ban, dvr_ind, rn)
    where e.rowid is null
```

Comment: im taking about ban = '4444444444' where dvr_ind='Y' are 4  in oms and 1 in enab

Answer (score 0):

As I understand , you want to "substract" results from enab table,

for this You must use MINUS operator ,

```
SELECT run_date,ban,dvr_ind FROM oms WHERE dvr_ind = 'Y'
    MINUS
SELECT run_date,ban,dvr_ind FROM enab WHERE dvr_ind = 'Y'
```

this will only return result from oms which are not in the enab table , 
more about minus and union operators here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm

Comment: Hi ogres, the above query works only for number data

Comment: what do you mean by "number data" ?

Comment: sorry, actually the above query is working fine but as i'm having duplicate data, i cannot use it.